# How to filter Mongo document based on sub-document in Java 8 Stream Filter

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, stream, java-stream

Am trying to filter a sub-document.

Sample Record:

```
[Document{{_id=597608aba213742554f537a6, upp_id=, content_id=597608aba213742554f537a3, idmapping=Document{{ptype=PDF, clientid=12345, normalizedclientid=12345, systeminstanceid=, sourceschemaname=, platforminternalid=0987654321}}, batchid=null, locale=en_US}}]
```

I need to filter using **idmapping.ptype = PDF**

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = mailboxitemCollection.find(whereClause).iterator();
List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<Document>();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  Document object = cursor.next();
  documentList.add(object);
}

 List<Document> outList = documentList.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getInteger(CommonConstants.VISIBILITY) == 1
            && (!StringUtils.isEmpty(req.ptype())? (p.getString("idmapping.ptype").equalsIgnoreCase(req.ptype())) : true)
            ).parallel().sequential().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

System.out.println(outList);
System.out.println(outList.size());
```

Am getting Null Point exception, am not able to read the sub/embed document from List documentList.

Thank you in advance!
Bharathi

Comment: NullPointer *where*?

Comment: maybe the `req` or `p.get*` is *null*, the `.parallel().sequential()...` is redundant and you also can use `collect(Colllectors.toList())` instead.

Comment: @Eugene - Nullpointer in '(!StringUtils.isEmpty(req.ptype())? (p.getString("idmapping.ptype").equalsIgnoreCase(req.ptype())) : true)'

Comment: so may be this `p.getString("idmapping.ptype")` is where you get the NullPointer?

Comment: @holi-java - getting value in req or p.get* and also, .parallel().sequential() getting correct result for other filter values, facing a issue while reading sub-documents.

Comment: what's I said is that it is redudant. you try to change a sequential stream to a parallel stream, and then change back to a sequential stream again. it is meaningless.

Comment: you can use `Objects.requireNonNull` to check each value whether is *null*, e.g: `Objects.requireNonNull(p.getString("idmapping.ptype"), "idmapping").equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.

Comment: You could include `'idmapping.ptype': {$eq: 'PDF'}` in your where clause thereby filtering the result set before it ever reaches the code you showed above. Of course, it's possible that this is redundant since you may **want** all ptypes in order to faciliate some other client side processing but based on the code above (you create the cursor then load everything from that cursor into a List and then use streams to filter the list) filtering server side, within Mongo, may be functionally equivalent and result in less network traffic.

Comment: Thank you all!
If I have used 'idmapping.ptype': {$eq: 'PDF'}, then i can able read from MongoDB. But, still am getting an Null Point Exception.

&& (!StringUtils.isEmpty(req.getPlatformType())? (Objects.requireNonNull(p.getString("idmapping.platformtype").equalsIgnoreCase(req.getPlatformType()))) : true)

Note - Am getting "req.getPlatformType()" value from request. But Am not able to read p.getString("idmapping.platformtype") from documentList sream/line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the mongo-java-driver you can't access the subdocument's fields directly. You should get the subdocument and after that the field of the subdocument like this:

```
String platformType =
 ((Document)p.get("idmapping")).getString("ptype");
```

In your case, change the filter to the following:

```
.filter(p -> p.getInteger(CommonConstants.VISIBILITY) == 1  && (!StringUtils.isEmpty(req.ptype()) ? (((Document)p.get("idmapping")).getString("ptype").equalsIgnoreCase(req.ptype())) : true))
```